# Signing operation with public key in bitcoin protocol (video lecture)

Tags: public-key, signature, cryptocurrency

At 5:26 in [this princeton coursera course video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/cryptocurrency/lecture/HWjti/bitcoin-scripts) the presenter says that the public key is used (by the recipient) to generate the signature to redeem the coins.

I'm a little confused here. If the public key is public information, and it's being used to generate the signature, then when is the private key used? I would have thought that the recipient would need to sign something with the private key.

Comment: I assume what he actually meant was "a signature is created using the private key associated to this public key" but "sign with this public key" is just so much shorter...

Comment: Thank you (I hope you're right). The general lack of precision in the language in that course is terrifying.

Comment: @user1883050 You see more of this, e.g. the class `X509Certificate2` from Microsoft may also "contain" a private key (if it is present at all). Of course a certificate doesn't contain any private key, but there might be one associated with the certificate. Personally I hate this practice, it is supposed to simplify things, but it actually only makes it harder to understand. Besides that, it's just incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The] presenter says that the public key is used (by the recipient) to
>   generate the signature to redeem the coins. [...] 
>   If the public key is public information, and it's being used to
>   generate the signature, then when is the private key used?

It's common to say something is signed with a public key or with a certificate (which is really just a public key with associated data).
What this actually means is something like

> Signed with the private key associated to this public key.

or

> Signed such that this public key can verify the signature.

As you can see this is much longer and linguistically more complicated than

> Signed with this public key.

so one does also (commonly?) see this latter writing.

---

In the concrete instance of the video it is said that the sender specifies a public key which can authorize further transactions (?) to be done with the coins (?) and its up to the recipient to generate a signature that can be verified with this public key (which is obviously only possible for the actual recipient).